# Change position of ylabel in MATLAB subplots

Tags: matlab, plot, label, subplot

Suppose that we have this figure with 4 subplots in `MATLAB R2015a`:

[image]

How can i change difference position (`ylabel`) to center?

Comment: you have just added the `ylabel` for the last subplot. Make it for the main plot not a subplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normalized units. Following is the code

```
set(y, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [v1, v2, v3]);
```

Use your values in place of v1, v2 and v3.. The normalized units are relative to [0,1]...

**Other Possible Solution**

You can also use:

```
ylabel('Difference', 'position',[x y z])
```

Comment: What is `y` in fist function?

Comment: @user2991243, that's the handle to the ylabel, which you could obtain by writing >>> y = ylabel('my label text');